# How do you delete a row that contains a certain value from a specific column across all tables in a database?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a query that searches the database for tables that have the column "GtNumber" that has a row numeric value of "2". I want to then remove these rows so that there are no rows within the database that contain a value of 2 for GtNumber.

Is there any way to get this all done with one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do it with a single query but you could query the system tables for any table that has that column name and then use that to create the delete scripts for you.

Select from those tables:

```
select 'select * from ' + t.name + ' where GtNumber = 2' 
from sys.tables t inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id
where c.name='GtNumber'
```

Delete from those tables:

```
select 'delete from ' + t.name + ' where GtNumber = 2' 
from sys.tables t inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id
where c.name='GtNumber'
```

Comment: Yep, then just take the resulting SQL statement from the output and execute it in a new window.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm fairly new at this and never copied the output SQL in a new window before. I selected all the output statements and copied them to a new query tab. I see a lot of "select * " statements. Now do I just copy the delete table statement and put it under all those select statements? It says it completed successfully but no rows are deleted.

Comment: The select statements are just for a sanity check to see what you are going to delete before you do it.  The delete statements will actually do the work.

Comment: @mbaxter You shouldn't need *both* statements, the `SELECT` is just for you to review what rows and what tables are going to be impacted (always a good idea). The `DELETE` will actually perform the work.

Comment: So basically the above select statement just checks what rows are going to be affected by the delete statement? So if it all checks out, I can simply run the delete statement from a new tab?

Comment: @mbaxter Yes, that is correct

Comment: I tried running the statment multiple times, but I still see it in the tables. The DB is set up so that I had to go into certain tables and remove the row first before I could remove it from another table. Is this why it isn't working?

Comment: When you run the delete statements if it's not deleting one of two things is happening.  Either the value is not 2 (maybe it's a string and "2"?) or you should see errors in the query output window.  If the table has foreign key dependencies you may have to rearrange the statements so that the dependencies are deleted first before the main source table.  Do you see any errors in the output window?

Comment: It allowed me to run the statement without any errors, so I think it's an issue with foreign keys. I picked out a delete statement from it and ran it on its own and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, for all intensive purposes your code works!

Comment: For the record what I did then was select all the output SQL from the delete statement and ran it in a new window multiple times until the parent rows were deleted.